# Handle multi-users security, ownership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I'm plan to develop an *asp.net mvc 4 (and simplemembership) website with Entity Framewok*, which will handle multiple users. A user has a page, like a facebook profile page, that it may post or edit. And I would like others users can also view and post on this page, but not edit those post, like facebook again.

I'm looking for an hour now some informations about how doing it, but I've found nothing. I'm new in asp.net and I don't know all the means. Roles do not seem to handle this kind of actions. Is there a way to do something like, in my controller, i can do something like when I create a post, i say the logged in user is owner, just him could delete this post, but all others could see it. But still, i don't know how to do for each user has his profile's page.

I take all advices, links to tuto or articles, reflections, ideas...
(sorry for my bad english)
Thank you

Comment: Take a look on asp.net profile provider (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281602/ASP-NET-Profile-Provider). It could help you to start or you can implement custome one.

Comment: @mipe34 Thanks, I've read the article, but I can't see how it could help me to bind an entire page to one user, because on my profile page other users can post, so i can't do something like, I return all the post of one user and that is my page... I don't know if i'm clear...it's a bit fuzzy to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look up the currently logged in user using simplemembership like this:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

To get the current user you can query your repository, like this for example:

```
var currentUser = db.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).Single();
```

**EDIT2: Missed changing a field from my Model to yours, fixed**

Based on your comment, i'll try to write a small example using the standard Scaffolded CRUD Delete Method in MVC4 and this assumes the Post model has a UserId property/field:

```
 [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
 public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id) 
 {
     var currentUser = db.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).Single();
     Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);      
     if (post.UserId==currentUser.UserId)
     {
        {
          db.Posts.Remove(post);
          db.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }  
     }    
  }
```

Comment: Assuming a user has poted a status. Is it possible to write something like that in my delete actionresult : if userid of my post = userid of User.Identity.Name then i can delete it, else i can't ?

Comment: Thanks, i think it's what i need to handle this issue.

Comment: Just modified my example slightly to match your model and the default SimpleMembershipProvider field names.